# Can I sell shares with old-fashioned paper certificates online?

Tags: united-kingdom, shares, online-brokerage

I have the paper certificates in my name, of some ordinary shares that were bought in 2009 in the UK.  Can I sell them online?

Comment: You cannot sell them online. You will have to send the share certificates to the broker, who is helping you to sell them. Check here http://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?t=2734811

Answer (score 1):

Having just investigated this for some REL shares I have in paper form you can transfer them into a broker such as TD direct and then sell them  total cost is around 12.95 for TD